# Inconsistent results between LU decomposition in R and Python

Tags: python, r, matrix, matrix-decomposition

I have the following matrix `A` in R:

```
           # [,1]       [,2]   [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] -1.1527778  0.4444444  0.375  0.3333333
# [2,]  0.5555556 -1.4888889  0.600  0.3333333
# [3,]  0.6250000  0.4000000 -1.825  0.8000000
# [4,]  0.6666667  0.6666667  0.200 -1.5333333

A <- structure(c(-1.15277777777778, 0.555555555555556, 0.625, 0.666666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, -1.48888888888889, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 
0.375, 0.6, -1.825, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.8, -1.53333333333333), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    NULL))
```

I compute its LU-decomposition as follows:

```
library(Matrix)
ex <- expand(lu(t(A)))
L <- ex$L
P <- ex$P
C <- U <- ex$U
C[lower.tri(U)] <- L[lower.tri(L)]

print(C)

# 4 x 4 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
           # [,1]       [,2]       [,3]          [,4]
# [1,] -1.1527778  0.5555556  0.6250000  6.666667e-01
# [2,] -0.3855422 -1.2746988  0.6409639  9.236948e-01
# [3,] -0.3253012 -0.6124764 -1.2291115  9.826087e-01
# [4,] -0.2891566 -0.3875236 -1.0000000 -2.220446e-16
```

On the other hand, this is the Python code for the same job:

```
lu, piv = scipy.linalg.lu_factor(A.T, check_finite=False)

print(lu)

# [[ -1.15277778e+00   5.55555556e-01   6.25000000e-01   6.66666667e-01]
 # [ -3.85542169e-01  -1.27469880e+00   6.40963855e-01   9.23694779e-01]
 # [ -2.89156627e-01  -3.87523629e-01   1.22911153e+00  -9.82608696e-01]
 # [ -3.25301205e-01  -6.12476371e-01  -1.00000000e+00   7.69432827e-16]]
```

I'm wondering why the two `C` and `lu` matrices in R and Python (respectively) are not the same. The point is that I have to get the same result as Python version (i.e. matrix `lu`). Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is embarrassing to realize 1.5 years later that my original answer is not fully correct. While it correctly pointed out that the rank-deficiency of `A` in the question is the cause, it is incorrect to attribute this as the root cause. **The real issue is the non-unique choice of pivot**, which could happen (although less likely) even if `A` is full-rank. Given that this post has been viewed 700+ times and has a score of 6, I might have misled many readers. SORRY!

I posted [Write a trackable R function that mimics LAPACK's dgetrf for LU factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51687808/4891738) and answered it just now. The question contains a `LU` function for LU factorization without pivoting, and the answer contains two functions `LUP` and `LUP2` for a version with row pivoting that are consistent with LAPACK's *dgetrf*, which underlies the dense method of `Matrix::lu` and R base function `solve.` In particular, the `LUP2` function allows one to track the factorization step by step. I will use this function here for investigation.

---

So you are factorization the transpose of `A`.

From the output of R and Python we see that they yield identical 1st pivot `-1.1527778` and 2nd pivot `-1.2746988`, while the 3rd pivot differs. So there is definitely something interesting happening when the factorization has done the first two columns / rows and proceeds to the the 3rd column / row. Let's pause R's LU factorization at this point:

```
oo <- LUP2(t(A), to = 2)
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] -1.1527778  0.5555556  0.6250000  0.6666667
#[2,] -0.3855422 -1.2746988  0.6409639  0.9236948
#[3,] -0.3253012 -0.6124764 -1.2291115  0.9826087
#[4,] -0.2891566 -0.3875236  1.2291115 -0.9826087
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 2
#attr(,"pivot")
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

At this point, the Gaussian elimination has reduced `t(A)` to

```
getU(oo)
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] -1.1527778  0.5555556  0.6250000  0.6666667
#[2,]  0.0000000 -1.2746988  0.6409639  0.9236948
#[3,]  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.2291115  0.9826087
#[4,]  0.0000000  0.0000000  1.2291115 -0.9826087
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 2
```

Wow, we see something really interesting now: the 3rd and 4th rows only differ by a sign change. Then the Gaussian elimination is not unique, because either `-1.2291115` or `1.2291115` can be a pivot as they have the same absolute value.

Clearly, R has chosen `-1.2291115` as the pivot, but Python has chosen `1.2291115` as the pivot. A row exchange between 3rd and 4th rows will happen in Python. In your question, you didn't report what permutation index Python gives you, but it should `1, 2, 4, 3`, instead of the `1, 2, 3, 4` in R.

---

Either way, the `U` factor ends up with a row of zeros in the bottom, so that `t(A)` or `A` is not full-rank. If you want to see a more consistent behavior between two software, you'd better try a full-rank matrix. In that case, it is less likely that you will have more than one choices for a pivot during LU factorization. You can generate a random full-rank matrix in R by

```
A <- matrix(runif(16), 4, 4)
```

Comment: You are right. Given the full rank matrix, I get the same output.