# Write a trackable R function that mimics LAPACK's dgetrf for LU factorization

Tags: r, function, matrix, matrix-factorization

There is no LU factorization function in R core. Although such factorization is a step of `solve`, it is not made explicitly available as a stand-alone function. Can we write an R function for this? It needs mimic LAPACK routine [`dgetrf`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d6a/dgetrf_8f.html). `Matrix` package has an [`lu` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562228/4891738) which is good, but it would be better if we could write a **trackable** R function, that can

- factorize the matrix till a certain column / row and return the intermediate result;
- continue the factorization from an intermediate result to another column / row or to the end.

This function would be useful for both educational and debugging purpose. The benefit for education is evident as we can illustrate the factorization / Gaussian elimination column by column. For debugging use, here are two examples.

In [Inconsistent results between LU decomposition in R and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41570787/4891738), it is asked why LU factorization in R and Python gives different result. We can clearly see that both software return identical 1st pivot and 2nd pivot, but not the 3rd. So there must be something interesting when the factorization proceeds to the 3rd row / column. It would be good if we could retrieve that temporary result for an investigation.

In [Can I stably invert a Vandermonde matrix with many small values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51662728/4891738) LU factorization is unstable for this type of matrix. In my answer, a 3 x 3 matrix is given for an example. I would expect `solve` to produce an error complaining `U[3, 3] = 0`, but running `solve` for a few times I find that `solve` is sometimes successful. So for a numerical investigation, I would like to know what happens when the factorization proceeds to the 2nd column / row.

Since the function is to be written in pure R code, it is expected to be slow for a moderate to big matrix. But performance is not an issue, as for education and debugging we only use a small matrix.

---

**A little introduction to dgetrf**

LAPACK's dgetrf computes LU factorization with row pivoting: `A = PLU`. On exit of the factorization,

- `L` is a unit lower triangular matrix, stored in the lower triangular part of `A`;
- `U` is an upper triangular matrix, stored in the upper triangular part of `A`;
- `P` is a row permutation matrix stored as a separate permutation index vector.

Unless a pivot is **exactly zero** (not up to some tolerance), factorization should proceed.

---

**What I start with**

It is not challenging to write a LU factorization with neither row pivoting nor "pause / continue" option:

```
LU <- function (A) {

  ## check dimension
  n <- dim(A)
  if (n[1] != n[2]) stop("'A' must be a square matrix")
  n <- n[1]

  ## Gaussian elimination
  for (j in 1:(n - 1)) {

    ind <- (j + 1):n

    ## check if the pivot is EXACTLY 0
    piv <- A[j, j]
    if (piv == 0) stop(sprintf("system is exactly singular: U[%d, %d] = 0", j, j))

    l <- A[ind, j] / piv

    ## update `L` factor
    A[ind, j] <- l

    ## update `U` factor by Gaussian elimination
    A[ind, ind] <- A[ind, ind] - tcrossprod(l, A[j, ind])

    }

  A
  }
```

This is shown to give correct result when pivoting is not required:

```
A <- structure(c(0.923065107548609, 0.922819485189393, 0.277002309216186, 
0.532856695353985, 0.481061384081841, 0.0952619954477996, 
0.261916425777599, 0.433514681644738, 0.677919807843864, 
0.771985625848174, 0.705952850636095, 0.873727774480358, 
0.28782021952793, 0.863347264472395, 0.627262107795104, 
0.187472499441355), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))

oo <- LU(A)
oo
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981  0.2878202
#[2,] 0.9997339 -0.3856714 0.09424621  0.5756036
#[3,] 0.3000897 -0.3048058 0.53124291  0.7163376
#[4,] 0.5772688 -0.4040044 0.97970570 -0.4479307

L <- diag(4)
low <- lower.tri(L)
L[low] <- oo[low]
L
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[2,] 0.9997339  1.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[3,] 0.3000897 -0.3048058 1.0000000    0
#[4,] 0.5772688 -0.4040044 0.9797057    1

U <- oo
U[low] <- 0
U
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981  0.2878202
#[2,] 0.0000000 -0.3856714 0.09424621  0.5756036
#[3,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.53124291  0.7163376
#[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.00000000 -0.4479307
```

Comparison with `lu` from `Matrix` package:

```
library(Matrix)
rr <- expand(lu(A))
rr
#$L
#4 x 4 Matrix of class "dtrMatrix" (unitriangular)
#     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
#[1,]  1.0000000          .          .          .
#[2,]  0.9997339  1.0000000          .          .
#[3,]  0.3000897 -0.3048058  1.0000000          .
#[4,]  0.5772688 -0.4040044  0.9797057  1.0000000
#
#$U
#4 x 4 Matrix of class "dtrMatrix"
#     [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       
#[1,]  0.92306511  0.48106138  0.67791981  0.28782022
#[2,]           . -0.38567138  0.09424621  0.57560363
#[3,]           .           .  0.53124291  0.71633755
#[4,]           .           .           . -0.44793070
#
#$P
#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "pMatrix"
#            
#[1,] | . . .
#[2,] . | . .
#[3,] . . | .
#[4,] . . . |
```

Now consider a permuted `A`:

```
B <- A[c(4, 3, 1, 2), ]

LU(B)
#          [,1]         [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.5328567   0.43351468 0.8737278  0.1874725
#[2,] 0.5198439   0.03655646 0.2517508  0.5298057
#[3,] 1.7322952  -7.38348421 1.0231633  3.8748743
#[4,] 1.7318343 -17.93154011 3.6876940 -4.2504433
```

The result is different from `LU(A)`. However, since `Matrix::lu` performs row pivoting, the result of `lu(B)` only differs from `lu(A)` in the permutation matrix:

```
expand(lu(B))$P
#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "pMatrix"
#            
#[1,] . . . |
#[2,] . . | .
#[3,] | . . .
#[4,] . | . .
```

Comment: `pracma` package also has an `lu` function, but it does not apply pivoting. Readers can verify (using matrix `B`) that it is equivalent to function `LU` in my question. `pracma::lu` is poorly written with a double loop-nest at R-level. `LU` uses a single R-level loop hence is a better implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's add those features one by one.

---

#### with row pivoting

This is not too difficult.

Suppose `A` is `n x n`. Initialize a permutation index vector `pivot <- 1:n`. At the `j`-th column we scan `A[j:n, j]` for the maximum absolute value. Suppose it is `A[m, j]`. If `m > j` we do a row exchange `A[m, ] <-> A[j, ]`. Meanwhile we do a permutation `pivot[j] <-> pivot[m]`. After pivoting, the elimination is as same as that for a factorization without pivoting, so we could reuse the code of function `LU`.

```
LUP <- function (A) {

  ## check dimension
  n <- dim(A)
  if (n[1] != n[2]) stop("'A' must be a square matrix")
  n <- n[1]

  ## LU factorization from the beginning to the end
  from <- 1
  to <- (n - 1)
  pivot <- 1:n

  ## Gaussian elimination
  for (j in from:to) {

    ## select pivot
    m <- which.max(abs(A[j:n, j]))

    ## A[j - 1 + m, j] is the pivot
    if (m > 1L) {
      ## row exchange
      tmp <- A[j, ]; A[j, ] <- A[j - 1 + m, ]; A[j - 1 + m, ] <- tmp
      tmp <- pivot[j]; pivot[j] <- pivot[j - 1 + m]; pivot[j - 1 + m] <- tmp
      }

    ind <- (j + 1):n

    ## check if the pivot is EXACTLY 0
    piv <- A[j, j]
    if (piv == 0) {
      stop(sprintf("system is exactly singular: U[%d, %d] = 0", j, j))
      }

    l <- A[ind, j] / piv

    ## update `L` factor
    A[ind, j] <- l

    ## update `U` factor by Gaussian elimination
    A[ind, ind] <- A[ind, ind] - tcrossprod(l, A[j, ind])

    }

  ## add `pivot` as an attribute and return `A`
  structure(A, pivot = pivot)

  }
```

Trying matrix `B` in the question, `LUP(B)` is as same as `LU(A)` with an additional permutation index vector.

```
oo <- LUP(B)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981  0.2878202
#[2,] 0.9997339 -0.3856714 0.09424621  0.5756036
#[3,] 0.3000897 -0.3048058 0.53124291  0.7163376
#[4,] 0.5772688 -0.4040044 0.97970570 -0.4479307
#attr(,"pivot")
#[1] 3 4 2 1
```

Here is a utility function to extract `L`, `U`, `P`:

```
exLUP <- function (LUPftr) {
  L <- diag(1, nrow(LUPftr), ncol(LUPftr))
  low <- lower.tri(L)
  L[low] <- LUPftr[low]
  U <- LUPftr[1:nrow(LUPftr), ]  ## use "[" to drop attributes
  U[low] <- 0
  list(L = L, U = U, P = attr(LUPftr, "pivot"))
  }

rr <- exLUP(oo)
#$L
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[2,] 0.9997339  1.0000000 0.0000000    0
#[3,] 0.3000897 -0.3048058 1.0000000    0
#[4,] 0.5772688 -0.4040044 0.9797057    1
#
#$U
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981  0.2878202
#[2,] 0.0000000 -0.3856714 0.09424621  0.5756036
#[3,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.53124291  0.7163376
#[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.00000000 -0.4479307
#
#$P
#[1] 3 4 2 1
```

Note that the permutation index returned is really for `PA = LU` (probably the most used in textbooks):

```
all.equal( B[rr$P, ], with(rr, L %*% U) )
#[1] TRUE
```

To get the permutation index as returned by LAPACK, i.e., the one in `A = PLU`, do `order(rr$P)`.

```
all.equal( B, with(rr, (L %*% U)[order(P), ]) )
#[1] TRUE
```

---

#### "pause / continue" option

Adding "pause / continue" feature is a bit tricky, as we need some way to record where an incomplete factorization stops so that we can pick it up from there later.

Suppose we are to enhance function `LUP` to a new one `LUP2`. Consider adding an argument `to`. The factorization will stop when it has done with `A[to, to]` and is going to work with `A[to + 1, to + 1]`. We can store this `to`, as well as the temporary `pivot` vector, as attributes to `A` and return. Later when we pass this temporary result back to `LUP2`, it need first check whether these attributes exist. If so it knows where it should start; otherwise it just starts right from the beginning.

```
LUP2 <- function (A, to = NULL) {

  ## check dimension
  n <- dim(A)
  if (n[1] != n[2]) stop("'A' must be a square matrix")
  n <- n[1]

  ## ensure that "to" has a valid value
  ## if it is not provided, set it to (n - 1) so that we complete factorization of `A`
  ## if provided, it can not be larger than (n - 1); otherwise it is reset to (n - 1)
  if (is.null(to)) to <- n - 1L
  else if (to > n - 1L) {
    warning(sprintf("provided 'to' too big; reset to maximum possible value: %d", n - 1L))
    to <- n - 1L
    }

  ## is `A` an intermediate result of a previous, unfinished LU factorization?
  ## if YES, it should have a "to" attribute, telling where the previous factorization stopped
  ## if NO, a new factorization starting from `A[1, 1]` is performed
  from <- attr(A, "to")

  if (!is.null(from)) {

    ## so we continue factorization, but need to make sure there is work to do
    from <- from + 1L
    if (from >= n) {
      warning("LU factorization of is already completed; return input as it is")
      return(A)
      }
    if (from > to) {
      stop(sprintf("please provide a bigger 'to' between %d and %d", from, n - 1L))
      }
    ## extract "pivot"
    pivot <- attr(A, "pivot")
    } else {

    ## we start a new factorization
    from <- 1
    pivot <- 1:n    

    }

  ## LU factorization from `A[from, from]` to `A[to, to]`
  ## the following code reuses function `LUP`'s code
  for (j in from:to) {

    ## select pivot
    m <- which.max(abs(A[j:n, j]))

    ## A[j - 1 + m, j] is the pivot
    if (m > 1L) {
      ## row exchange
      tmp <- A[j, ]; A[j, ] <- A[j - 1 + m, ]; A[j - 1 + m, ] <- tmp
      tmp <- pivot[j]; pivot[j] <- pivot[j - 1 + m]; pivot[j - 1 + m] <- tmp
      }

    ind <- (j + 1):n

    ## check if the pivot is EXACTLY 0
    piv <- A[j, j]
    if (piv == 0) {
      stop(sprintf("system is exactly singular: U[%d, %d] = 0", j, j))
      }

    l <- A[ind, j] / piv

    ## update `L` factor
    A[ind, j] <- l

    ## update `U` factor by Gaussian elimination
    A[ind, ind] <- A[ind, ind] - tcrossprod(l, A[j, ind])

    }

  ## update attributes of `A` and return `A`
  structure(A, to = to, pivot = pivot)
  }
```

Try with matrix `B` in the question. Let's say we want to stop the factorization after it has processed 2 columns / rows.

```
oo <- LUP2(B, 2)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981 0.2878202
#[2,] 0.9997339 -0.3856714 0.09424621 0.5756036
#[3,] 0.5772688 -0.4040044 0.52046170 0.2538693
#[4,] 0.3000897 -0.3048058 0.53124291 0.7163376
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 2
#attr(,"pivot")
#[1] 3 4 1 2
```

Since factorization is not complete, the `U` factor is not an upper triangular. Here is a helper function to extract it.

```
## usable for all functions: `LU`, `LUP` and `LUP2`
## for `LUP2` the attribute "to" is used;
## for other two we can simply zero the lower triangular of `A`
getU <- function (A) {
  attr(A, "pivot") <- NULL
  to <- attr(A, "to")
  if (is.null(to)) {
    A[lower.tri(A)] <- 0
    } else {
    n <- nrow(A)
    len <- (n - 1):(n - to)
    zero_ind <- sequence(len)
    offset <- seq.int(1L, by = n + 1L, length = to)
    zero_ind <- zero_ind + rep.int(offset, len)
    A[zero_ind] <- 0
    }
  A
  }

getU(oo)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981 0.2878202
#[2,] 0.0000000 -0.3856714 0.09424621 0.5756036
#[3,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.52046170 0.2538693
#[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.53124291 0.7163376
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 2
```

Now we can continue factorization:

```
LUP2(oo, 1)
#Error in LUP2(oo, 1) : please provide a bigger 'to' between 3 and 3
```

Oops, we have wrongly passed an infeasible value `to = 1` to `LUP2`, because the temporary result has already processed 2 columns / rows and it can not undo it. The function tells us that we can only move forward and set `to` to any integers between 3 and 3. If we pass in a value larger than 3, a warning will be generated and `to` is reset to the maximum possible value.

```
oo <- LUP2(oo, 10)
#Warning message:
#In LUP2(oo, 10) :
#  provided 'to' too big; reset to maximum possible value: 3
```

And we have the `U` factor

```
getU(oo)
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 0.9230651  0.4810614 0.67791981  0.2878202
#[2,] 0.0000000 -0.3856714 0.09424621  0.5756036
#[3,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.53124291  0.7163376
#[4,] 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.00000000 -0.4479307
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 3
```

The `oo` is now a complete factorization result. What if we still ask `LUP2` to update it?

```
## without providing "to", it defaults to factorize till the end
oo <- LUP2(oo)
#Warning message:
#In LUP2(oo) :
#  LU factorization is already completed; return input as it is
```

It tells you that nothing further can be done and return the input as it is.

Finally let's try a singular square matrix.

```
## this 4 x 4 matrix has rank 1
S <- tcrossprod(1:4, 2:5)

LUP2(S)
#Error in LUP2(S) : system is exactly singular: U[2, 2] = 0

## traceback
LUP2(S, to = 1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 8.00   12   16   20
#[2,] 0.50    0    0    0
#[3,] 0.75    0    0    0
#[4,] 0.25    0    0    0
#attr(,"to")
#[1] 1
#attr(,"pivot")
#[1] 4 2 3 1
```